# How to configure shortcuts of a Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm coding a Firefox extension that allows user to use shortcuts on Spotify Web Player and I want them configurable.

The first approach is this example [using options page](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/favourite-colour)

However, how can I load the customized shortcuts on the manifest.json?

[Link to my repository extension](https://github.com/TsunDoge/spotify-hotkeys-firefox)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no such functionality for user's defining shortcuts in Firefox as you can see [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384). In the future, maybe this resolved.

Currently, you can play with a work around:

- You have to catch the keypress events. The background script is usually not open to catch key presses.
- To catch keypresses on web pages, you will have to use a content script that sends messages to the background script. The content script is injected to the open web page and insert methods for catching keypresses, and then send a message to the background script with information on which keys are pressed.
- Then the background script will send another message to the script responsible this executing the command.

Disclaimer: I have no tested, so proceed with caution.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go till https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384 lands. You have to create your own interface for the custom shortcuts you provide in your extension in the meantime.

Comment: I'll try this "hack" until mozilla team implements something. Thank you for the approach.